# Why is my "time since" template filter not working?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I am currently using Django-Messages and can see the exact date and time the message was received.  I'm trying to build a template filter that takes the date/time received and then calculates if it was Today, Yesterday, last week, ect.

## Inbox.html

```
Inbox | Received Today
{% for message in messages %}
    {% if message.date|hours_ago:24 %}
        Today
        Sent by: {{ message.sender }}
        {{ message.body }}
    {% elif message.date|hours_ago:48 %}
        Yesterday
        Sent by: {{ message.sender }}
        {{ message.body }
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

## Template Filter

```
@register.filter
def hours_ago(time, hours):
    return time + timedelta(hours=hours) < timezone.now()
```

This is currently not working.  For example, {% if message.date|hours_ago:3 %} will display all emails regardless of message.date value.

It may be of help to know that message.date by itself (without the template filter) is displayed in the format of "Dec. 17, 2014, 6:21 a.m", I don't know if this has something to do with why the template filter isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling your `hours_ago()` function from the Python shell and you'll find out about the first problem: `

```
>>> TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to function
```

IOW, that should be:

```
return time + timedelta(hours=hours) < timezone.now()
```

notice the parens...

Now the above expression still won't do what you hope:

```
>>> timezone.now()
datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 18, 9, 26, 57, 920331)
>>> t = datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 5)
>>> hours_ago(t, 24)
True
>>> hours_ago(t, 48)
True
```

The point is : actually your function checks of the passed in `datetime` is "more than `hours` old". It means that for a 30 days old datetime, this will return `True` for any value of `hours` less than (approximately) `720` (=> `30 * 24`).

Obviously you need to think a bit more about you expect this filter to do exactly... Writing unit tests first might help too.

Comment: Yes I accidentally forgot the () when I copy and pasted.  I have updated the original post.

Comment: Then you're left with a wrong logic in your filter... and possibly an incomplete spec, cf my updated answer.